# In Python OpenCV I cannot setImageCOI - are the operations on arrays part of the standard library?

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to change the Image Channel of Interest (setImageCOI), Python gives me this error:

```
im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.setImageCOI(im, 1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setImageCOI'
```

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/operations_on_arrays.html

Do I need to specially install the modules that allow for operations on arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is implemented in the `cv` module under `SetImageCOI` (notice the capital `S`):

```
import cv
cv.SetImageCOI(im, 1)
```

Comment: In the Python version of the library functions seem to start with lowercases.  Still, converting it to the original uppercase doesn't work for me. cv2.SetImageCOI(im, 1) leads to 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SetImageCOI'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SetImageCOI'

Comment: You're using the `cv2` module, not the `cv` module. That method doesn't exist in the `cv2` module.

Comment: Thanks!  That helped answer my question.  cv2.cv.SetImageCOI(im, 1) now asks me for an IplImage as I suspected it would ... on to that problem!
TypeError: Argument 'image' must be IplImage

Comment: The `cv2` and `cv` modules *sometimes* are compatible. Use `cv.LoadImage` instead of `cv2.imread` and it should work.